# How to redirect the standard output of all the content within a shell script to a log file?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, redirectstandardoutput

Let us consider there are many system commands inside a shell script with each of them returning some content to stdout or stderr.

Instead of performing redirection for  each and every command separately is there any way to redirect all the stdout or stderr generated from the shell script to a log file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the obviously simple solution would be to use

```
./scriptfile.sh > foo.log
```

thus all stdout generated withing the scriptfile goes to foo.log

i guess however, that your question is directed towards a solution that works from withing the script.
you can (re)direct a file-descriptor to a given file using the exec command (line 2 in the following snippet will redirect stdout to foo.log):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 1>>foo.log

echo blue
echo blart
```

Comment: btw, this trick (`exec 1>>foo.log`) was rather shamelessly stolen from configure as generated by autoconf...